# I need help defining a case statement in SQL db2-400

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am using SQL, IBM Data Studio, db2-400. I need help writing a case statement that looks for the length of a field and returns a blank if it is not equal to 14, I have tried many ways without success, below is my latest attempt.

```
CASE 
   WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(FFIUPCN) <> '14' 
     THEN '' 
   ELSE 
     FFIUPCN 
 END AS "UPC (if applicable)"
```

The error I get is that the token "<>" is not valid.

Comment: what does "UPC(if applicable)" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main issue is that you are missing a `)`

```
CASE 
   WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(FFIUPCN)) <> 14 
     THEN '' 
   ELSE 
     FFIUPCN 
 END AS "UPC (if applicable)"
```

but you shouldn't be comparing a numeric, returned by `length()`, to a sring `'14'`.  But Db2 is implicitly converting it.

Comment: Thank you Charles, that was a rookie mistake on my part, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: How can I set up this statement to test for multiple conditions, in addition to length I would also like to check to make sure the value is not '99999999999999' (14 9's)?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple conditions you can nest your case statements

```
   Select
        case when FIUPCN+FFIUPCN2 = 0 
           then case when FIUPCN >= value  then FIUPCN + 1 
                else FIUPCN + 2 end
        else
           case when FIUPCN >= value
               then case when FIUPCN <> '' 
                       then FIUPCN + 3
                    else prvca1 end
           else 
            case 
                when FIUPCN >= FIUPCN2 and FIUPCN3 <> 0 then FIUPCN + 4
                when FIUPCN >= FIUPCNX and FIUPCNY <> 0 then FIUPCN + 5
            else prvca1 end
        end
    end 
    from table
```